# How can make the preload image the same size of the real image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, lazy-loading

I have a webpage including some images with different width and height, to improve speed of loading the page, I want implement the lazy loading. But the default preloaded picture always has different size of real picture since I do not know the size of picture before loading. How can I make the preload image the same size of the real image?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo G_STATIC_URL; ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo G_STATIC_URL; ?>/js/jquery.lazyload.min.js"></script>

$(function() {

        $("img").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("data-original",$(this).attr("src"));
            $(this).attr("src", "<?php echo G_STATIC_URL; ?>/common/loading_b.gif");
        });

        $("img").lazyload({
            placeholder : "<?php echo G_STATIC_URL; ?>/common/loading_b.gif",
            effect : "fadeIn"
        });
    });
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Actually, no code. It is a question not limited to any special code. In general, The height and wide of the default preload image is different to the real picture, if we do not know the size of real picture before. What I ask is how can make them same. a general solution to all pictures with different size.

Comment: I know about this. I asked for the basic code because, every lazy loading plugin has different way of implementation!

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar, thanks for you remind, I add some code of it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find the dimensions of an image using Javascript until it has fully loaded.

If your HTML is being rendered on a server, you could print the width and height of each images directly into the image tag:

```
<img src="..." width="<?= $width ?>" height="<?= $height ?>" />
```

Another option would be to use a standard ratio for each pre-loading box, and resize your loaded image to fit within this ratio, at least then nothing changes shape at image-load time.

Comment: Thanks Alex, is there possible to make the default preload picture is the same picture of real picture but with low quality. I do not know how to implement this by js code.

Comment: @PhilipSong unfortunately not. Again, you *could* do this by creating a smaller image on the server and loading those first, but it's not an easy solution and means sending 2 versions of each image.